# Is there any way to install virtual audio cable application without prompt message using powershell command

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

Virtual audio cable installer does not have silent mode on. Therefore  can not use following command

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath 'c:\software\vac460\setup64.exe' ArgumentList"/S /v/qn"
```

Is there another way to install application without user intervention.

Comment: Are you sure it does not have a silent switch? Sometimes these options are not obvious or common. You might ask the vendor or creator of that setup file.

Comment: When I run above command it throws exception as '/S is invalid argument'. For other application its working fine.

Comment: Sometimes its not `/S` ... try to run it with a `/?`. Sometimes its `-s` or `--s` or `-silent` or `/q` ... or whatever ... you should contact the vendor and ask for support. You could even try to extract the files. If there's an msi package in it you could install this silent.

Answer (score 2):

I emailed the developer for VAC to ask this same question. He responded:

> You can add "-s -k 30570681-0a8b-46e5-8cb2-d835f43af0c5" to the
> setup.exe command line.

I have confirmed that this worked using VAC 4.64:

```
.\setup64.exe -s -k 30570681-0a8b-46e5-8cb2-d835f43af0c5
```

The installer returns immediately and the process installs in the background. However the installation only took about 10 seconds at most. If you needed to catch a failed install I would suggest [monitoring the active audio device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59398725/69683) and timing out based on that.

Installation log file (on my system) went to `C:\Program Files\Virtual Audio Cable\install.log`

Comment: This did not work for me with the most current version

Comment: I wonder if the GUID changes on each version - unfortunately I don't know how the developer was able to determine the GUID so I can't repeat his process. That said, he did just respond to a regular email so you can just ask him. Feel free to update this answer with the newer GUID if you find out.

Answer (score 1):

The [Virtual Audio Cable](https://vac.muzychenko.net) product never had the "virtualaudiocable.exe" installer. I'm afraid you are confusing it with something else.

Comment: This is just an example. Yes they have different nane. I can correct that.

Comment: Could you please explain why do you need a silent installation? Usually it is required if dozens of hundreds copies of a product are installed for short time.

Comment: I need to create a powershell script to install VAC along with other applications. Rest of application do support silent installation expect VAC.

Comment: Such silent installation makes sense only if you have many licenses. Please email me with order information, and I will provide a silent installer for you.

Comment: I have sent you an email with required information. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I have replied to the appropriate person.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way on how i made it work with silent installation. I've used **-i** **-h**

```
#$version       = $env:chocolateyPackageVersion -replace "(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+).*",'$1.$2.$3' 

$toolsDir   = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
$fileLocation = Join-Path $toolsDir 'VBCABLE_Setup_x64.exe'
$packageName = 'VBCable'


$packageArgs = @{
  packageName    = $packageName
  fileType       = 'exe'
  file           = $fileLocation
  silentArgs     = " -i -h "
  softwareName   = 'VBCable'
  validExitCodes= @(0, 3010, 1641)
  # Checksums are now required as of 0.10.0.
  # To determine checksums, you can get that from the original site if provided. 
  # You can also use checksum.exe (choco install checksum) and use it 
  # e.g. checksum -t sha256 -f path\to\file
  checksum       = '186892503330970C8E8D561ADF9B71BD15CD93589306EC00FA60009EBF611EE6'
  checksumType   = 'sha256' #default is md5, can also be sha1, sha256 or sha512
  checksum64     = '186892503330970C8E8D561ADF9B71BD15CD93589306EC00FA60009EBF611EE6'
  checksumType64 = 'sha256' #default is checksumType

}
Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage @packageArgs
```

Comment: This is for VBCable, not VAC as the original poster is asking about

Answer (score 0):

-s -k GUID did not work for me any more, but I found the solution at
https://github.com/gcloudrig/gcloudrig/issues/40, https://github.com/gcloudrig/gcloudrig/commit/68c0c4a289d7127ee3c9b147fd392d150bfa0eab and https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/963b71526274f236ddc82e6becf1ef501310ffda47100d3be52b9c8e3ca9b937?environmentId=120 :

```
VBCABLE_Setup_x64.exe -h -i -H -n
```

Run this from an elevated command prompt, of course.

But it still asked me whether I trust this driver.
To solve that, too: Open any CAT-file of this driver and click the "View certificate" button, click the button to install the certificate, then find it in certmgr.msc under "Other People", export it as CER-file and frist run

```
certutil.exe -addstore "TrustedPublisher" vbcable.cer
```

on any target machine before running the setup